# Обмен нод местами при сортировки в линейном списке C

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, сортировка, структуры-данных

Есть функция линейной сортировки списка на Си

```
void linear_sort(struct List* _list){
    struct Node *curNode = begin(_list);
    struct Node* memory;
    while(next(curNode) != end(_list)){
        if(strcmp(curNode->key.string, next(curNode)->key.string) > 0){
            memory = curNode;
            printf("%s%d%s\n", memory->key.string, memory->key.value, memory->data);
            printf("%s%d%s\n", curNode->key.string, curNode->key.value, curNode->data);
            printf("%s%d%s\n", curNode->next->key.string, curNode->next->key.value, curNode->next->data);
            curNode->key = next(curNode)->key;
            curNode->data = next(curNode)->data;
            printf("%s%d%s\n", curNode->key.string, curNode->key.value, curNode->data);
            curNode->next->data = memory->data;
            curNode->next->key = memory->key;
            printf("%s%d%s\n", curNode->next->key.string, curNode->next->key.value, curNode->next->data);
        }
        curNode = next(curNode);
    }
}
```

Я хочу обменять ключи и данные двух нод местами, у меня получается перенести данные и ключ второй ноды в первую, предварительно сохранив в переменной memory данные первой ноды, но во вторую из первой не получается, так как почему-то содержимое memory->data и memory->key само изменяется. Пытаюсь дебажить printf и вот что выдает:
[image: вывод]

Как можно сделать, чтобы в следующие ноду клались ровно те значения, которые имеет memory в начале функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `memory` - это не копия текущего узла, а ещё один указатель на память.

Вам нужно что-то вроде:

```
    struct Node tmp = { .key = curNode.key, .data = curNode.data };
    curNode->key = next(curNode)->key;
    curNode->data = next(curNode)->data;
    next(curNode)->key = tmp->key;
    next(curNode)->data = tmp->data;
```